# Dictionary KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have the following code:

```
def search_for_person(name):
    with open("address.txt", "r") as book:
        records = re.split("[-]+", book.read(), re.M)
        for data in records:
            record = get_record(data)
            if record['Name'] == name:
                print record


def get_record(string):
    return dict(re.findall("^(.*): (.*)$", string, re.M))
```

When I use this to try and locate a record, I get the following output:

```
Enter name: Daniel Ghi
{'Home Phone No.': 'Example', 'Mobile Phone No.': 'Example', 'Name': 'Daniel Ghi
', 'Address': 'Example'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "address.py", line 35, in <module>
    search_for_person(name)
  File "address.py", line 18, in search_for_person
    if record['Name'] == name:
KeyError: 'Name'
```

As you can see, this **does** actually print out the correct data, but it still comes up with a KeyError, and I'm not sure why. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Can you add the code where you create your dictionary ?

Comment: Nothing you've shown demonstrates that `'Name'` is always a key in `record`; your only `print` comes *after the access*, in cases where we know it's there.   Put `print record` in there after `record = get_record(data)` and see what it looks like.

Comment: There is probably a second record in `records` which doesn't have the required key.

Comment: 'name' is not always a key.

Comment: DSM: That then prints out all the records that get made, still with the KeyError

Comment: @dantdj: are you saying that it never prints out a record which doesn't have `Name` as a key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It prints out the correct data, then *keeps running* and raises a `KeyError` on later data.

Most likely your file ends with a `------` string, so your `split` produces a list with an empty string at the very end, which then produces an empty dict, which naturally doesn't have any keys in it.

Easy fix is to just skip the `data` if it's empty, or only whitespace, or if `record` is empty.  More robust fix is to avoid using `[]` syntax when you can't be sure what keys each dict actually has; use `record.get('Name', None)` instead.